# On module navigation, module styles are mixing

Tags: angular, module, styles, overriding, ng-zorro-antd

I have two modules, admin and front module. And I have two theme.less file, different for each module. When I'm navigating from one module to another module the are mixing. But if I go directly to one module the style is okay this happens when I'm navigating to one module.

**admin.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: "app-admin",
  templateUrl: "./admin.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./admin.component.css","./admin-theme.less"],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

**front.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: "app-front",
  templateUrl: "./front.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./front.component.css","./front-theme.less"],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

**angular.json**

```
"styles": [
 "node_modules/ng-zorro-antd/ng-zorro-antd.min.css",             
 "src/styles.css" 
 ],
```

On `admin.component.html` and `front.component.html` I have just router-outlet. And I'm using ng-zorro.

Answer (score 1):

`ViewEncapsulation.None` moves all CSS into DOM and not on Component Level. Try Removing that line and check it will work for your case.

Read more about [ViewEncapsulation](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewEncapsulation).

Comment: inside this two modules I have modules as sub module, now ``` ["./admin.component.css","./admin-theme.less"] ``` and ``` ["./front.component.css","./front-theme.less"] ``` are not effecting sub modules. How can I fix this?

Comment: In that case use ViewEncapsulation.Emulated. You might have to do some minor changes in CSS.

Comment: after this, theme.less isn't working. Do you know another way for importing styles. I searched but didn't found. Btw thank you very much